# how to set visible/invisible the buttons when i place pointer/touch the buttons?

Tags: android, image, button

i am making one app in that i want to display a list of images.normally i can able to display the images. i have displayed these images with navigation bottons left and right. for reference. when i press left displays previous and right button displays next image. but actually i dont eant to display buttons always , when my pointer go there, it has to visible.
otherwise only images has to display.
any ideas please..
and also my images are all different sizes,how can i get the emulator size? then its easy to resize images and set in drawable list.

[image]

```
    code for left button:
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/bttn"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bttn"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="ClickHandler2"
    android:background="@drawable/android_lbutton"
    />
    in drawable/android_lbutton

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/timthumb6"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/timthumb3"
      android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/timthumb8" />
     </selector>
```

here timthumb6,timthumb3,timthumb8 are three left buttons with diff colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put both the buttons in invisible state initially...and implement ontouch listeners for both the buttons and for the imageview as well... in ontouch of the button set it visible.. and in ontouch of imageview set both the buttons invisible again..

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to make a selector?

Press = true; Focus = true; drawable = "arrow"

Press = false; Focus = False; drawable = "transparent"

Answer (score 0):

```
Button _button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    _button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Or u can first put them invisible then u can make it visible wherever u want